# 2D Collision response - rotating, moving polygon hitting a wall

Tags: math, game-physics

I'm trying to bounce a polygon that has both velocity and angular velocity off a (immovable) wall when one of the vertices collides with it. I can detect the collision, and I've worked out how to calculate the inputs and know what outputs I need, but haven't been able to find or work out an implementation for the response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function collisionResponse(
    c, // object center of mass position
    v, // velocity of object
    a, // the angular velocity of the object
    p, // point of contact with line
    n  // normalized normal of line
) {
    //  Make a vector from center mass to contact point
    cp = p - c;

    //  Total velocity at contact point (add angular effect)
    pv.x = v.x - cp.y * a;
    pv.y = v.y + cp.x * a;

    //  Reflect point of contact velocity off the line (wall)
    rv = reflect( pv, n );

    // ..magic happens.. ??

    result.v = ?? // resulting object velocity
    result.a = ?? // resulting object angular velocity
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While not entirely trivial, the calculation can be reduced to high school level math. I'll walk most - but not all - of the way: the final quadratic equation I leave to you to write down and solve. [There is no LateX on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow), so bear with me here.

The answer depends on several additional parameters:  (1) The mass of the object M, (2) The [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) of the object, denote as I, (3) An [elasticity coefficient for the collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision#Types_of_collisions), say alpha - meaning, how much kinetic energy is conserved in the collision: 0 for complete loss of energy (plastic collision), 1 for complete preservation of kinetic energy (perfect elastic collision).

The wall operates some yet unknown [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) J (essentially F dt) on the object, along rv (in your notation), resulting both in change of straight and angular momentum, according to the Newtonian mechanics rules:

> J x cp = I * diff(a)      (this is a *cross product*, more below)
>
> J = M * diff(v)

Say the initial velocity is Vi and the final one Vf, and similarly the initial angular velocity Ai and final Af. So:

> Vf = Vi + J/m
>
> Af = Ai + (J x cp) / I

The initial and final kinetic energy are:

> Ei = 0.5 * M * Vi^2   + 0.5 * I * Ai^2
>   Ef = 0.5 * M * Vf^2   + 0.5 * I * Af^2

Letting Vf and Af in:

> = 0.5*M*(Vi + J/m)^2 + 0.5*I*(Ai + (J x cp) / I)^2

Now we demand that the final kinetic energy be alpha times the initial kinetic energy (this is the definition of elasticity of a collision).  If you equate those two expressions you'd get a quadratic equation in J - jot down the solution and you have Vf and Af as requested.

Note about cross product:   in 2D the product `J x cp` can be reduced to a scalar obtained as `J*cp*sin(theta)`, where theta is the angle between cp and rv.

Theta is signed and care *must* be taken with its sign!    In a nutshell, if your a (the angular momentum) is positive for counter-clockwise rotation - then theta, the angle between J and cp, should be the counter-clockwise angle from J to cp.  e.g. *+45* when cp is 45 deg counter-clockwise from J.   (in radians of course)

That's about the best I can do in SO's markdown. Feel free to ask if more clarifications are needed.

[Edits:]
(1) I fixed -cp back to cp.  This order of multiplication (Jxcp) already flips the sign, no need for an extra flip.

(2) Here's a LateX-less graphic attempt:
[image: J cp]

(3) Only when assuming uniform mass density, are m and I related by a constant multiplicative coefficient. If you do assume that you can drop one of the inputs - but they are typically kept as two, as they form a more straightforward way of describing the object.

(4) Clarification: the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) I is not a variable to be deduced from the equation, it is a parameter of the problem. Just like the mass M  - essentially, how hard it is to accelerate the object -it describes how hard it is to rotate the object.  The detailed (not complicated) integral calculation is at the wikipedia link,  and for simple objects - balls, cylinders, cubes - you'd easily find canned results online.

Comment: Thank you very mich Ofek, I'm going to try to work through this tonight.

Comment: Sorry, what does diff mean? diff(a), diff(v)

Comment: Difference.   diff(v) = Vf - Vi

Comment: Sorry, my math skills are pretty weak. I'm still not understanding how to use the equations as they require J, but we need the resulting velocity and angular velocity to calculate J... and those are the results I'm looking to get. One other thing... do we need the mass of the object? Wouldn't it be the same for any mass?

Comment: Thank you for all your time. I guess I was confused, I do have J, it is my vector rv. It's I that I don't know the value of. So my function would be: `result.v = v + rv; result.a = a + cross(rv, cp) / i;` But I still don't have I.

Comment: Doesn't fit in a comment - I expanded the answer with some details on I .

Comment: @OfekShilon, first of all, thank you kindly, this answer was useful to me as well :) I am still working through the math involved but wanted to know if this method generalizes to inelastic collisions of two bodies in motion with one being possibly static? If not, can you briefly explain how the new angle and force velocity vectors could be calculated?

Comment: @GoofyBall: one body being static doesn't mean the collision is inelastic - you can simulate this state by giving one body infinite (ie very large) mass.
If you do want to reduce elasticity (regardless of one body being static), make alpha (the 'elasticity coefficient') less than 1.

Comment: Yes, I understand that 0 < cor < 1 determines how much kinetic energy is conserved. The OP's original question applied to a single body. What I meant to ask was suppose there are two colliding bodies with with velocity vectors v1, v2, angular velocities a1, a2 and moment inertias I1, I2 and density masses, colliding at a point p, can we solve for all of these using J?

Comment: This section on Wikipedia has a GIF similar to what I describe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional The formulas apply for particles with no angular velocity though.

Comment: The equations for two finite-mass objects are different but actually much simpler and don't require the use of impulses - just conservation of linear momentum, angular momentum and energy (up to elasticity coefficient).